# installing express without npm for the MEAN stack

Tags: macos, homebrew

My El Capitan shows node installed in **/usr/local/bin/node**, but  `$which npm`  reports nothing.
I have Angular installed and which to play around with the MEAN stack which requires express and mangoDB.

My current path is: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Online reading to install express shows I must issue npm command.
Can I install express using brew instead?  Thanks

Comment: What is your PATH ?

Comment: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

Comment: Why are you doing which npm but say you have /usr/local/bin/node ? What not say if you have npm and where that is

Comment: to see if the npm command is available or not on my system so that I can install express in my web project dir.

Comment: Why mention  /usr/local/bin/node ? what has that to do with npm

Comment: Because online reading indicate that npm comes bundled with nodeJS

Comment: You have the executable node what is that to do with npm?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by downloading and installing node.js which also installed npm.